# Нахождение числа которое делится нацело на все элементы списка

Tags: python

Пробую так, но не работает:

```
a=0
i=1
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
while i==1:
    a=a+1
    if a % b==0:
        print(a)
        i=i+1
    else:
        pass
```

Как сделать так, чтобы работало?

Comment: очевидно, что нужно поочередно делить на элементы списка, а не на сам список

Comment: для этого списка ответ будет `232792560`. для перебора это многовато, есть алгоритм эффективнее: `НОК(b[0], НОК(b[1], НОК(b[2], ...)))` где `НОК` - наименьшее общее кратное, реализация найдется в интернете.

Answer (score 2):

В школе это называлось "наименьшее общее кратное"

И для его нахождения не обязательно перебирать все натуральные числа

```
НОК = 1
for x in list:
   НОК = найти_НОК(x, НОК)
```

Answer (score 2):

Нахождение [наименьшего общего кратного (НОК)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5) для списка чисел:

```
from functools import reduce

def gcd(a, b):
    while(b):
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    return abs(a * b) // gcd(a, b)

res = reduce(lcm, range(2, 21))
print(res)
# 232792560
```