# Почему в цикле while не работает оператор and?

Tags: python, python-3.x

мучаю проект Эйлера. Данный код должен выдать число, которое одновременно делиться и на 3, и на 5 без остатка. Однако выдает лишь первое число, которое отвечает одному из условий, в данном случае число - 3. Вопрос, почему не работает оператор and? Пересмотрел все статьи, которые находил, но ответа не нашёл. (Задача №5 ПЭ)

```
y = 1 
x = 1 
while y == 1: 
    if (x % 3 != 0) and (x % 5 != 0): 
        x = x + 1
    else: 
        print(x) y = 0
```

Comment: что значит `код должен выдать число`? Ваш код выводит на печать все числа которые __не__ удовлетворяют условиям `if`

Comment: [Задача №5 ПЭ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/976337/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Вы ссылку открывали?

Comment: Открывал, она дает решение задачи, но не отвечает на  вопрос почему не  работает оператор "and" в цикле.

Comment: У Вас неправильное условие, остаток должен быть равен 0. У Вас наоборот, следовательно, первая часть False и исполнение переходит в ветку `else`. Я исправил свой ответ, попробуйте решение.

Comment: если вы идете "от противного", то проверяйте так: `if x % 15 != 0` или так: `if not (x % 3 and  x % 5)`

Comment: nomnoms12 , спасибо, помогло. Понял в чем была ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Оператор `and` работает, подставьте 3 в условие: `(x % 3 != 0)`
Будет `False`, следовательно всё выражение `False` и исполняется ветка else, то есть печатается `3`

Насколько я понял, Вам нужно найти НОК. Вот исправление для Вашего кода:

```py
x = 1
while True:
    if (x % 3 == 0) and (x % 5 == 0):
        print(x)
        break
    else:
        x += 1
```

Оптимизированный алгоритм поиска НОК:

```py
a = 3
b = 5

m = a * b
while a != 0 and b != 0:
    if a > b:
        a %= b
    else:
        b %= a
x = m // (a + b)

print(x)
```

Comment: Поясню, код должен выдать число, которое будет делиться и на 3 и на 5 без остатка одновременно, такое число - 15. Но сейчас этот код игнорирует оператор "and" и выводит число, которое соответствует одному из условий, в данном случае 3 т.к. оно наступает первым. Вопрос почему оператор "and" не работает?

Comment: y = 1
x = 1
while y == 1:
    if (x % 3 != 0) and (x % 5 != 0) :
        x = x + 1
    else:
        print(x)
        y = 0

Comment: @ВладимирАнтонов Исправил, попробуйте. Возможно, Вам поможет.